# How to extract the JSON data from HttpResponse in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I am sending a JSON Http Response as shown below in web API, the JSON data is present in the response.Content

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var LoginDetailsResponse = new LoginDetails { LoginToken = "Token" , LoginDescription = "Desc" };
            response.Content =  
                new ObjectContent<LoginDetails>(LoginDetailsResponse,
                            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            return response;
```

And the object that is send as a JSON format is :

```
public class LoginDetails
    {
        public string LoginToken { get; set; }
        public string LoginDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

And the following is the angular js code that i used to send a request and extract the JSON content:

```js
var Submit = function() {

  var httpResponseRef = $http({
    url: 'http://wycvwetebx056.com:81/',
    method: "GET"
  });

  httpResponseRef.then(successloginCallBackRef, errorloginCallBackRef, notifyCallbackRef);


};

// when it is a success it call's successloginCallBackRef function

var successloginCallBackRef = function(httpLoginResponseMessage) {

  var status = httpLoginResponseMessage.status;
  var response = httpLoginResponseMessage.data; // returns everything as a string type.
};
```

But the **httpLoginResponseMessage.data** is not returning the data as expected, it seems to contain the following.

```
"StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.JsonContent[LoginDetails.LoginDetailsResponse], Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}"
```

I can see that i have the json content, but i am not sure how to extract that while using angular js.

Comment: Did you try [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) =

Comment: Well, maybe your server is sending it double encoded for some reason? If the response header says that is is JSON, $http would treat it as such. Else, you can parse the data with JSON.parse as mentioned in the first comment. If you use Chrome Dev tools you can look at the response that comes back in the Network tab to see if it is a string or whether it is parsing correctly.

Comment: @adeneo  : Guys, yeah i had tried JSON.parse as well, but it seems to be throwing the 'Unexpected token S' error. I checked on that and found that if there are no quotes it would throw that error. But i don't find a necessity of explicitly appending quotes in the beginning.

Comment: That's confusing? If you do `console.log( typeof response  )` what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Why not rely on the built in methods to take care of content negotiation.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Login()
{
    var s = new LoginDetails { LoginToken = "read from somehere"};
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, s);               
}
```

This will return you a JSON structure to your angular http call. You can read the data property in your success callback and it will be a js object where you can access the `LoginToken` property.

```
var successloginCallBackRef = function(response) {

  var status = response.status;
  var d = response.data; 
  console.log(d.LoginToken);
};
```

Comment: I tried entering Request.CreateResponse in VS2012, but i keep getting the red squiggly line. Tried auto resolving it, but no luck there as well. Is there any dll or namespace that i should be inheriting to make this code work?

Comment: It is defined in `System.Net.Http` namespace. Which version of  dot net framework are you using ?

Comment: Yeah i used the same namespace, but i guess its because i was using Controller instead of APIController in the web API. It works now. Thanks! But i hope it is in the JSON format as well. I meant the response data.